# Rename InnoDB column in Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, innodb

How to rename one column with InnoDB (Symfony and Doctrine) if I have OneToOne relation ? In Phpmyadmin, my column is grey : edition impossible

Answer (score 0):

On your relation, you can set both name and referencedColumnName , like this :

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="OtherEntity")
 * @JoinColumn(name="other_entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $otherEntity;
```

Comment: Thanks but I just want rename finally my column (example : with Phpmyadmin) :)

Comment: if you do a php bin/console doctrine:schema:update, it will rename your column ;)